# Find and sub in one line using Python re

Tags: python, regex

Is it possible to both find and substitute in the same line in Python using the `re` module? i.e. to also return what has been substituted (in a similar way to how `re.subn` returns the number of substitutions).

For example, I have text of the form `"FOO BAR PART 1"`, what I want to do is to convert this to `"FOO BAR"` and `"PART 1"`.

All I can think of is to use something like:

```
title_old = "FOO BAR PART 1"
parts_found = re.findall(r"PART [0-9]*$", title_old )   ## i.e. search for term
if parts_found != []:
    part_string = parts_found[0]
    title_new = re.sub(re.escape(parts_found[0]),"",title_old )  ## If that term exists, then substitute it.
```

Comment: provide a sample input along with expected output..

Comment: I would love to know if there's an equivalent of `perl -pe 's{foo}{bar}g'`. Until I find such a think I'm going to hold onto perl for dear life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a separate method instead of a replacement pattern and pass the match object to that method. You may declare a varaiable to keep track of all replaced texts there.

See [`re.sub` reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub):

> If *repl* is a function, it is called for every non-overlapping occurrence of pattern. The function takes a single match object argument, and returns the replacement string.

```
import re

replacements = []
def repl(m):
    replacements.append(m.group(0))  # Add found match to the list
    return "";                       # We remove the match found

title_old = "FOO BAR PART 1"
print(re.sub(r"PART [0-9]*$", repl, title_old))
print(replacements)
```

See [demo](http://ideone.com/7qW0oa)

Result:

`FOO BAR 
['PART 1']`

Answer (score 1):

Just do a split according to the space which exists before `PART`.

```
re.split(r'\s+(?=PART\s\d*$)', s)
```

*Example:*

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "FOO BAR PART 1"
>>> re.split(r'\s+(?=PART\s*\d*$)', s)
['FOO BAR', 'PART 1']
>>> s = "PART 1"
>>> re.split(r'\s+(?=PART\s*\d*$)', s)
['PART 1']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
import re

title_old = "FOO BAR PART 1"
title_new = re.sub(r" PART \d+$", "", title_old)
```

See [`re.sub()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) for more details.